# How to calculate the margin in SVM light?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, max-margin

I'm using Support Vector Machine in a project.  The  library chosen is SVM light of Joachims: http://svmlight.joachims.org/

I have the need to calculate the margin. Namely, given a training set of data I have to calculate the margin of the better hyperplane found.   But I do not see a direct way to do this in svm light.  So I'll ask you to know how to do it.
The data should be linearly separable and in this case I expect a positive margin, but there is also the remote possibility that in some case the data arent't linearly separable and in this case I expect a negative margin. (I use hard margin)
Is there a possibility to do that in this library?

Answer (score 1):

For the linearly separable case (using linear kernel), there is a script on SVM Light site's FAQ that can give you the weight vector (w) from the `svm_model` output file, http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm%5Flight/svm_light_faq.html (look for the question "How can I get the weight vector of the hyperplane for a linear SVM?").

With the weight vector you can calculate the margin by doing one over its norm: $\frac{1}{\lVert w \rVert}$

Comment: In case the link goes dead at some point in future, this page version is actually [available on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170917044231/http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_light_faq.html)